# UTF-8 returns wrong character

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, character-encoding

I have been converting the particular decimal value to string using the UTF-8 encoding, but I have returned with "?" instead of "ü". But On using UTF-7 encoding returns correct answer. kindly provide suggestion.

```
        System.Text.Encoding encoding;
        encoding = Encoding.UTF8;            
        byte[] textbyte = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(252) };
        int byteLength = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(252) }.Length;
        string temp = encoding.GetString(textbyte, 0, byteLength);
```

Expected Result : temp should have "ü";

Actual Result  :  temp = "?"

Comment: Are you checking the "actual result" by printing it to the `Console`? If so, you need to set [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I will add those result char to collection. I will try to match the collection with user defined character for search operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working example

```
var encoding =new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true,true);
var word = "ü";
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(word);
string temp = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```